# PHP: Breaking a string into multiple lines and manipulating each line separately

Tags: php, split

I have pulled a string out of a database it contains some html code as for example:

```
something about thing one<br>
now comes the second thing<br>
we're not done yet, here's another one<br>
and last but not least is the fourth one<br>
```

So I have four lines but when I print out the string I get an output like in the example above. What'd I'd like to do is manipulate every line so that I'd be able to do this:

```
<span>something about thing one</span>
<span>now comes the second thing</span>
<span>we're not done yet, here's another one</span>
<span>and last but not least is the fourth one</span>
```

I'd also like to have a counter for how many lines are there in a string (like for this one there are 4 lines) so I can set "odd" and "even" class for the span.

How do I do this?

Comment: <br> is the only HTML and it will always be there?

Comment: Use `explode` to split the string, and a `foreach` loop to print each line the way you want it. What's the problem?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Yes <br> is the only html and will allways be there.

Comment: Then it is as easy as @Barmar suggests.  Give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)() function with `PHP_EOL` constant as delimiter:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $original);
```

After you can iterate the returned array to parse lines, for example:

```
foreach ( $lines as $line )
{
    echo '<span>'.$line.'</span>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but all I get is one span element and everything what was in the string. Not separated by line, each into its own span.

Comment: Quite strange, I've tested it and all is done correctly...

Comment: Thank you, with PHP_EOL added it now works correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the string with the delimiter and then use a foreach loop to get the answer you want.

```
$input = "omething about thing one<br>
now comes the second thing<br>
we're not done yet, here's another one<br>
and last but not least is the fourth one<br>";
```

//Explode the input string with br as delimiter

```
  $data = explode ('<br>', $input );
```

//Filter $data array to remove any empty or null values

```
$data   = array_filter($data);
```

//to get total data count

```
$count  = count($data);
```

//now use loop to what you want

```
$i = 1;
foreach ( $data as $output) 
{
    //create class based on the loop
    $class = $i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
    echo '<span class="'. $class .'">'. $output .'</span>';
    $i++;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode` to split and I would prefer `for` loop in these scenario instead of `foreach` as the latter will return an empty `span` tags in the end since it loops five times.

```
$arr    =   explode("<br>",$value);
for($i=0;$i<count($arr)-1; $i++){
echo "&lt;span&gt;".$arr[$i]."&lt;/span&gt;<br>";
}
```

To get the count you can use `count` function:

```
echo count($arr)-1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but all I get is one span element and everything what was in the string. Not separated by line, each into its own span.