# Find the first line break after string

Tags: php

I need to get a sub-string that contains data until the first line break after my string.

I've tried strstr() to find the string I'm looking for. However, it's defining an end for substr() that's an issue as I can only pass Integers to it and the content could have different lenght.

```php
if (strstr($body, 'Post Code:')){
    $postcode = substr(strstr($body, 'Post Code:'), 10, $lastChar);
    if (strstr($body, 'First name:')){
        $firstName = substr(strstr($body, 'First name:'), 11, $lastChar);;
    } elseif(strstr($body, 'Last name:')){
        $lastName= substr(strstr($body, 'Last name:'), 10, $lastChar);;
    } elseif(strstr($body, 'Comments:')){
        $comments = substr(strstr($body, 'Comments:'), 9, $lastChar);;
    }
    $queryFields = "INSERT INTO fields (ID, Postcode, First_name, Last_name, Comments) VALUES ('$id', '$postcode', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$comments')";
    $resultFields = mysqli_query($this->connection, $queryFields);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150644/php-breaking-a-string-into-multiple-lines-and-manipulating-each-line-separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strpos() can help you to locate the first end of line in a string, so you can easily know when to cur your string.

```
if ($postcode = strstr($body, 'Post Code:')){
    $postcode = substr($postcode, 10, strpos($postcode, PHP_EOL)-10);
    if ($firstName = strstr($body, 'First name:')){
        $firstName = substr($firstName, 11, strpos($firstName, PHP_EOL)-11);
    } else {$firstName = '';}
    if($lastName = strstr($body, 'Last name:')){
        $lastName = substr($lastName, 10, strpos($lastName, PHP_EOL)-10);
    } else {$lastName = '';}
    if($comments = strstr($body, 'Comments:')){
        $comments = substr($comments, 9, strpos($comments, PHP_EOL)-9);
    } else {$comments = '';}

    $queryFields = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "INSERT INTO fields (ID, Postcode, First_name, Last_name, Comments) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($queryFields, 'issss', $id, $postcode, $firstName, $lastName, $comments);
    $resultFields = mysqli_stmt_execute($queryFields);
}
```

I took the liberty to change one or two things I considered as problematic :

- You were using elseif between every condition, implying that there cannot be a lastName and a firstName in the same $body.
- All the variables you were using weren't defined in every case.
- Your SQL request was unprotected to SQL injections, so I used a prepared statement.

Also, I left $id in the query, as you did, assuming you were defining it's value somewhere.